# Difference between total session duration and total page visit duration

Tags: google-analytics

My Google Analytics data for a particular window looks like this:

**Audience Section**:

> Total Sessions: 5,677
>   Avg Time per session: 248 seconds
>   Pages/session = 2.73
>   Total Pageviews = 5,677 * 2.73 = 15,498
>   **Total duration (by sessions): total sessions * avg time per session = 5,677 * 248 = 1,407,896**

**Behavior Section**:

> Total PageViews: 15,517 (very close to the audience report)
>   Avg Time per page: 142 seconds
>   **Total duration (by pageviews): total pageviews*avg time per page = 15,517 * 142 = 2,203,414**

Shouldn't both the duration numbers atleast be close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Avg Time / Session` is calculated based on the times of `lastPageview - firstPageview` per the google documentation:

- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1006253?hl=en
- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en

`Avg Time / Pageview` is calculated based on time between known pages viewed.

Taking the standard example from the source above, if you viewed this information for a single visitor with the following:

1. Pageview @ 10:00
2. Pageview @ 10:05
3. Pageview @ 10:10 (end of visit)

Here, the Session length is 10 minutes whereas Time/Pageview is 5 minutes/pageview.

Calculating the Session vs Pageview difference as you did above in this scenario would yield the same discrepancy (10 vs 15).